# Exchange (EWS 2.2) return a null ICalUid

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS 2.2 to query an Exchange Server. Everything works find for all `Appointment` (I tested many hundred items without any problem) except one: The return `Appointment` has no `ICalUid`, how is this possible?

Here is my code

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
exchangeService.Credentials = ...;
exchangeService.Url = ...;

var results = exchangeService.FindItems(folderId, searchFilter, view);
```

My `PropertySet` is defined like this:

```
{ ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Categories, AppointmentSchema.ICalUid, 
AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType, 
AppointmentSchema.Duration };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally means the related properties haven't been set on whatever item your trying to access. You not using a CalendarView so its also possible that the item your trying to access isn't an Appointment (check the ItemClass), the best way to confirm is try to open the object in a Mapi editor like MfcMapi or OutlookSpy and you will be able to see the underlying properties are on the item.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I downloaded `OutlookSpy` and found that the GlobalObjectId (0x8033) was not in the property list. So this is obviously  my problem. The question is now: how is it possible that an `Appointment` has no Id?

Comment: I also checked the `ClassName` as you suggested and found "IPM.Appointment", which seems to be ok...

Comment: Missing GlobalObjectId are generally caused by third party client bugs CalCheck was designed to scan and fix this (along with other problems) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2678030

Comment: Thank you for the information. I suspect that this entry was created by a thrid party tool...